# mySQL not assigning name value to PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a project where I'm supposed to create a website that people can register and log in. I'm trying to do that thing where it will say in the corner "Logged in as ..."

This is part of the code that assigns the variable name to the name value in the database when the user logs in.

```
    $first = mysql_query("SELECT FirstName FROM students WHERE studentID = '$user' AND password = '$pass'");
    $firstname = mysql_fetch_array($first);
    $_SESSION['name'] = $firstname;
```

And this is the code on the website that displays the name

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
echo '<li class="disabled"><a href="#" disabled>Signed in as ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '</a></li>';
} 
?>
```

But when the website is actually ran the space is left blank. I know the variable is set because I replaced $_SESSION['name'] with some random string and it echo'd it fine. I also ran the SQL query and it gave me back the name. What am I missing from my code?

Comment: Do you have session_start(); ??

Comment: You're using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) & should use a [modern one](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You're *probably* **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from. 
You don't seem to be [hashing passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of them.

Comment: ...not to mention probable plain text password storage.

Comment: Yes I have session_start();, and Quentin, I have no intention of actually creating a user base because this is just a little project for school, but thank you for telling me and I'll take your advice if I want to start something serious

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array()`, as the name implies, returns an array of values. Not just the one column you have selected.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($first);
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['FirstName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`mysql_fetch_array($first);`

with

`mysql_fetch_array($first)['FirstName'];`

Also avoid using mysql_* function. They have been depricated.
Use mysqli_* instead or PDO

Comment: This `['FirstName ']` will result in not showing the row, since there's a space. Change to `['FirstName']`

Comment: opps, sorry typo, and I guess John beat me to first ans